# Load values from external file into pom.xml

Tags: postgresql, maven, flyway, properties-file

I am trying to read some parameters in a pom.xml from an external file. I am using [properties-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/index.html), but I don't really mind any other solution to read values from an external file as a variable in pom.

Here is my plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--<files>
                                <file>${apps.basedir}/apps/flywayvariables.properties</file>
                                <file>/home/gokul/git/sampleproject/apps/flywayvariables.properties</file>
                            </files>-->
                            <urls>
                                <url>file:///${apps.basedir}/apps/flywayvariables.properties</url>
                            </urls>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Here is where I am trying to use it:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sqlMigrationSeparator>__</sqlMigrationSeparator>
                    <locations>
                        <location>filesystem:${apps.basedir}/apps/flyway</location>
                    </locations>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9000/postgres</url>
                    <user>${dbuser}</user>
                    <flyway.user>${dbuser}</flyway.user>
                    <flyway.password>${dbpassword}</flyway.password>
                    <password>${dbpassword}</password>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>42.2.16</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>migrate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>migrate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And here is my properties file:

```
<properties>
    <dbuser>postgres</dbuser>
    <dbpassword>test1234</dbpassword>
</properties>
```

When I run mvn -X initialize, I get the following error:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.example.company:sampleapplication @ /home/gokul/git/sampleproject/apps/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) quiet = false
[DEBUG]   (s) urls = [file:////home/gokul/git/sampleproject/apps/flywayvariables.properties]
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Loading properties from URL file:////home/gokul/git/sampleproject/apps/flywayvariables.properties
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:7.0.1:migrate (migrate) @ apps ---
```

...
...
...

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.422 s (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-13T01:18:40+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/1237M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:7.0.1:migrate (migrate) on project apps: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
[ERROR] Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9000/postgres) for user 'null': The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
[ERROR] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] SQL State  : 08004
[ERROR] Error Code : 0
[ERROR] Message    : The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
```

I can see that the plugins are executed in the order I would want and yet the property is not loaded. The file path and permissions shouldn't be an issue since I created the properties file with the same user account as I am executing the maven project. *No password was provided* error changes to *authentication failed* error when I input the password manually and only keep the *$dbuser* as a variable. I have tried changing the names of the variables too, in vain. In the properties-maven-plugin configuration, I tried supplying *files* instead of *urls*, but it did not make any difference to maven.

Unfortunately none of the solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712885/how-to-load-an-external-properties-file-from-a-maven-java-project) question helps me.

Tried the following maven goals:

- initialize
- verify
- validate
- install
- properties:read-project-properties initialize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you need to write the properties file in the traditional fashion like

```
dbuser=postgres
dbpassword=test1234
```

Comment: surprisingly when I check this yesterday, it didn't work. But today it worked! Restart helps I must say. Never imagined I would have to supply a plaintext properties file, this isn't mentioned anywhere either. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why the properties plugin does not work, but Flyway itself supports multiple methods for storing these settings outside of the pom. See the [Flyway maven documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/maven/#configuration) for more details.

Below is some snippets from the link:

### Configuration Files

Flyway will search for and automatically load the `<user-home>/flyway.conf` config file if present.

It is also possible to point Flyway at one or more additional config files. This is achieved by supplying the System property `flyway.configFiles` as follows:

`mvn -Dflyway.configFiles=path/to/myAlternativeConfig.conf flyway:migrate`

See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/#config-files for more information.

### Maven Settings

Alternatively for storing the database user and password, Maven `settings.xml` files can also be used:

```
<settings>
   <servers>
       <server>
           <!-- By default Flyway will look for the server with the id 'flyway-db' -->
           <!-- This can be customized by configuring the 'serverId' property -->
           <id>flyway-db</id>
           <username>myUser</username>
           <password>mySecretPwd</password>
       </server>
   </servers>
</settings>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, since the previous answer helped me, I am not trying these, but nevertheless it would be a good alternative!